# Parsing xml from Jquery Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am having real problem with the following script where I am trying to compare the user selected input data (`#texto` div) to an AJAX called XML file and return an element (`price`) to a different div (`#divo`). It seems impossible to compare the `text1` variable to the different XML attributes ? When I enter the name of the attribute instead of the `text1` variable it does work.
I hope I am clear enough.

Thank you for your help!

First the XML file:

```
<priceitem>
<name itemname="Ham Brie"><price>9.00</price></name>
<name itemname="croque monsieur"><price>8.00</price></name>
</priceitem>
```

Now the jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
$("#texto").select(function() {
  var text1 = $("#texto").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "price.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
  parsexml(xml);
    }
  });


function parsexml(xml) {
  $(xml).find('priceitem').each(function() {
  var att = $(this).find('name').attr('itemname');
  var price = $(this).find('price').text();
  if (att == text1) {
    $('#divo').append(price);
  }
  else {
    alert('problem!');
  }
 });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

> I am having real problem with the following script where I am trying to compare the user selected input data (#texto div) to an AJAX called XML file and return an element (price) to a different div (#divo).

Thats the problem right there...

1. You can only call `val()` on form field controls - things that have a `value` attribute.
2. You are not going to get the desired value even if you were able to call `val` on a DIV because what you want is the value of the selection not the entire DIV. To get that you need to get that data from `window.getSelection()` in modern and standards browsers, or `document.selection.createRange()` in IE < 9.
3. Lastly `jQuery.select` only works on `input` and `textarea` elements as well, so the event will never even be fired for a DIV.

   [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/select/):

   > The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to  fields and  boxes.

   You will need to use a series of other events in order to do this like `mousedown` and `mouseup` but its going to be a bit more complex. Or, there may be a plugin you can use but I don't have one i can recommend.

---

`priceitem` is the root node so you cannot `find` it. You need to adjust your code like:

```
function parsexml(xml) {
  $(xml).find('name').each(function() {
  var att = $(this).attr('itemname');
  var price = $(this).find('price').text();
  if (att == text1) {
    $('#divo').append(price);
  }
  else {
    alert('problem!');
  }
 });
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2gt1f44f/

Comment: You are right on that part. However the script does not insert the variable price into #divo. and when I try to alert the var att I get an undefined????

Comment: What type of element is `#texto`? I think maybe you are confused on what the [`jQuery.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) function does and the event it binds to... You should post the relevant HTML you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Thank god for console.log!  I had a stupid error in my php script that generated the datalist (one extra space so text1 and att where never being equal.....Now it is working.   I cannot believe I spend hours on such a stupid mistake....Lesson: always use console.log.   Thank you everybody!

Comment: So how did you get the event to fire on a DIV?

Comment: Sorry, it has been a long day and I made a mistake.  I meant id for texto (referring to an input) and div for the answer.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense... Thanks for the follow up :-)